# Solving this coupled ODE system with sine

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> How to solve the ODE system: for $a,b$ constants
> $$\frac{dx(t)}{dt}=a  y(t)\sin t$$ $$\frac{dy(t)}{dt}=b x(t)$$

My attempt:
Combining the two equations, $$\frac{d^2 y}{dt^2}=b \frac{dx}{dt}=ab y \sin t $$ So we get a second order ODE only in $y$.  I know how to solve for constant coefficients but I don't know how to solve this. Solving this 2 degree would complete my argument. But how to do it?

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: Is it $\sin(t y(t))$ or $y\sin t$?

Comment: @Andrei it is simply $y sin t$. Following your suggestion I have edited it to make it more clear

Comment: The second order differential equation for $y$ is similar to the Mathieu equation- as such a closed form solution is improbable